# UITableView inside UICollectionView hangs while scrolling the UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

i have a `collectionview` with `flowlayout` pagination and inside the `collectionviewCell` i have added `tableview` so now the problem is whenever i scroll `collectionview` is getting hang or jerking and also suddenly increasing memory usage.

and then i remove the `tableview` from my `collectionviewCell` and it was running perfectly but my requirement is to put `tableview` inside `collectionCell` so what should i do ?

```
  //MARK:- CollectionView Methods


func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 2
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if section == 0 {

        return arrRecent.count
    }else {

        return arrAnswered.count
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if indexPath.section == 0 {

        if indexPath.row == 1 {

            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "HomeRadioSelectionCell", for: indexPath) as! HomeRadioSelectionCell

            cell.setupFields()

            cell.btnOptionOne.leftImage(image: UIImage(named: "ic_checked_radio")!, renderMode: .alwaysOriginal, state: .selected)
            cell.btnOptionOne.leftImage(image: UIImage(named: "ic_unchecked_radio")!, renderMode: .alwaysOriginal, state: .normal)

            cell.btnOptiontwo.leftImage(image: UIImage(named: "ic_checked_radio")!, renderMode: .alwaysOriginal, state: .selected)
            cell.btnOptiontwo.leftImage(image: UIImage(named: "ic_unchecked_radio")!, renderMode: .alwaysOriginal, state: .normal)

            cell.btnOptionthree.leftImage(image: UIImage(named: "ic_checked_radio")!, renderMode: .alwaysOriginal, state: .selected)
            cell.btnOptionthree.leftImage(image: UIImage(named: "ic_unchecked_radio")!, renderMode: .alwaysOriginal, state: .normal)
            //
            cell.btnOptionOne.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.btnOptionOneClick(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            cell.btnOptiontwo.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.btnOptionTwoClick(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            cell.btnOptionthree.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.btnOptionThreeClick(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)


            let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped))
            cell.imgHeader.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            cell.imgHeader.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)

            return cell

        }else if indexPath.row == 2 {


            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "HomeEmojiCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! HomeEmojiCollectionCell
            cell.setupFields()
            cell.slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.sliderValue(_sender:)), for: [.touchUpInside,.touchUpOutside,.touchCancel,.valueChanged])

            return cell
        }


        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! HomeCollectionViewCell
        cell.setupFields()
        cell.btnBar.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.barViewClick(_sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        cell.btnCancel.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.barCancelClick(_sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        return cell

    }else {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "AnsweredCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! AnsweredCollectionViewCell
        cell.setupChart()
        cell.cardView.enableRippleBehavior = false
        cell.cardView.inkView.inkColor = UIColor.clear
        cell.cardView.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        cell.cardView.clipsToBounds = true

        return cell

    }
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {

    if section == 0 {

         return UIEdgeInsets.init(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 5, right: 40)

    }else if section == 1 {

        return UIEdgeInsets.init(top: 0, left: 30, bottom: 5, right: 30)

    }else {

        return UIEdgeInsets.init(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

   var cellSize: CGSize = collectionView.bounds.size

            cellSize.width -= collectionView.contentInset.right - 5
            cellSize.width -= collectionView.contentInset.left - 5
            cellSize.height -= collectionView.contentInset.bottom


    return cellSize

}
```

**tableview mwthods inside the HomeCollectionViewCell file**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return 5
}



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tblView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HomeTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! HomeTableViewCell
    cell.btnOption.enableRippleBehavior = true
    cell.btnOption.setElevation(ShadowElevation(rawValue: 2), for: .normal)
    cell.btnOption.leftImage(image: UIImage(named: "ic_check")!, renderMode: .alwaysOriginal, state: .selected)
    cell.btnOption.leftImage(image: UIImage(named: "ic_uncheck")!, renderMode: .alwaysOriginal, state: .normal)
    cell.btnOption.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.btnOptionClick(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    return cell
}
```

please let me kn if you want to see more code :)

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: it's just normal collectionview methods and inside the cell there is table methods but wait m adding code  :)

Comment: Just do one thing comment the tap gesture code and see what happen. I think so you are adding the tap gesture on each cell which is causing the issue.

Comment: @MaheshDangar How many collectionViewCell is visible at a time on screen ?

Comment: @MandeepSingh no that cell is not causing the issue the only cell creating the problem is HomeCollectionViewCell

Comment: @SGDev 3 collectionViewCell is Visible both side partially cell  and middle cell fully just like pagination but yeah at a time 3 cell visible and load

Comment: Try to debug the code by commenting the line in HomeCollectionViewCell, that way you can be able to understand which line are causing the issue.

Comment: @MaheshDangar when your collectionViewCell is created, it is created all tableViewcCell inside the collectionViewCell in-respects of visible cell. put break point in cellForRow it is called 5 times, which is taking time by which jerking is occurring

Comment: @SGDev yeah but the only middle cell will be that collectioncell which will have tablevie other two will be normal cell so only that cell is taking load and u r right it's taking load because all 3 cell visible at the same time so what need to do to remove jerking :(

Comment: @MandeepSingh yes i have tried that way but the whole tableview is causing problem :( but my requirement is to use table in collectionview so give me any idea to remove jerking :(

Comment: @MaheshDangar you need to change you approach, by this way you can't handle jerking issues.

Comment: @SGDev like which approach ? to loading 3 cells or to loading table in cell ?